# Execute Process Task running PowerShell script fails with exit code -1073741790

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am trying to run a PowerShell script that a colleague wrote and deployed to run as an SSIS package.  He is able to run the script successfully within Visual Studio and it runs fine from the SQL Agent scheduler.

When I run the script - indeed, any PowerShell script - from an Execute Process task in Visual Studio, I get the same exit error code:

> The process exit code was "-1073741790" while the expected was "0".

As far as we can both tell, our development environments are almost identical.

Wondering if anyone has any insight or advice on how to debug and resolve.

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a security or trust issue. Please relax the powershell permissions on your system and then check again. You can do this by running this command:

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

That will determine if this is indeed an execution policy or something different and you can move on from there by changing the execution policy setting permanently, ad-hoc or by creating signed scripts.

[Using the Set-ExecutionPolicy Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx)

Comment: Just to make sure, you are running all of these from an elevated CMD prompt, correct?

Comment: Yes.  I imaged another workstation and the same scripts are working, so it may be something hosed up with the frameworks or other.  At this point it probably makes more sense to just bite the bullet and reinstall everything since I have a base image to start from.